# Highlight inherited members

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to visually separate an inherited class member, i.e. a variable that is defined public/protected in a superclass?

I noticed that it's possible to stylize abstract members separately...

I'm using Eclipse Ganymede.

Answer (score 2):

Open Window > Preferences.

Select General > Appearence > Colors and Fonts on the left.

On the right select Java > Inherited Members, and choose color you want.

This color will be used in hierarchy view for inherited members.

Comment: Is there a way to do this to highlight the code in the editor?

Comment: I'm not aware of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a clear difference in the hierarchy view of a given class (press F4 on the Class name).

Then press the "Show all inherited members" button on the detail view.

[alt text http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/images/hierarchy-lockview.png](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/images/hierarchy-lockview.png)

**Methods/variables declared in the current type are shown in blue, inherited ones in black.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the editor, then you probably mean overridden methods (not inherited), right?  If so, Eclipse indicates overridden methods in the editor with a green arrow pointing up to the left of the method signature.  Clicking on the green arrow takes you to the super-classes implementation of the method.

As for actually changing the color of the text, I don't know - the green arrow has always been enough for me.

Comment: No, I mean inherited, protected or public, class variables. So, if I use a protected variable from the superclass, I would instantly know that I don't need to look for a definition of that variable in the current class definition.